# Quickblox Google Login

Tags: authentication, google-plus, quickblox

I have already implemented Facebook login with my quickblox application, but I was wondering if there was any way to implement Google login as well? There's nothing on their documentation that would suggest that, but I was just wondering if anyone on here has figured out how to do it? Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean Google+ login?

Comment: yeah that is what i meant sorry

Comment: Have you managed a way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 2):

QuickBlox doesn't support Google+ out of the box like Twitter and Facebook,

but, anyway, you can implement Google+ login.

For example, you have Google+ email and you would like to use it to login to QuickBlox,

here is what you can do:

```
NSString *googleEmail = @""; 

[QBUsers logInWithUserEmail:googleEmail password:[googleEmail hash] delegate:self];
```

First time when you do this - this request will fail because you don't have such user.

You need to process this error and create new user:

```
QBUUser *user = [QBUUser user];
user.email = googleEmail;
user.password = [googleEmail hash];

[QBUsers signUp:user delegate:self];
```

and then repeat login request.

Fore more info you can refer [Users code sample](http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-users-ios)

And you can build password using any algorithm you want, this just an example with hash

make sense?

Comment: Thank you for the information. Exactly the same idea i had yesterday.

Comment: So how would the user login after the first time if they're not the one choosing their password?

Comment: you need to know only email. Then build password using some function from email