# Quickblox, what is externalID used for?

Tags: google-plus, quickblox

What is the externalID property for users used for in Quickblox? Would it allow me to use Google+ sdk to log in a user to my application and then create that user in the backend?

Comment: Please let me know if you managed to login using google plus account. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to login with Google+ [Quickblox Google Login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24831440/quickblox-google-login)

If you want to integrate QuickBlox, but you have already your User Base, you can use the **externalUserID** field. Just set it during the QuickBlox user registration.

Then, while working with QuickBlox users, you can refer to your original user by **externalUserID**