# Parse with QuickBlox

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, quickblox

QuickBlox allows to add an `external ID` parameter per user to incorporate with an existing user base. But my question is:

Groups are automatically created based on certain situations; I don't have the user.ID of quickblox, but I have the externalID(PK of my User table) of each user that I need to make occupant of the group chat. How do I create a group chat and specify occupants by their externalIDs and not the `user.ID` parameter?

Answer (score 0):

To do such integration you have to create a QuickBLox user for each Parse user. And each QuickBLox user has to have an **external ID** with a value of Parse user ID.

You can create QuickBlox users on demand, here is a good example how to do it [Quickblox Google Login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24831440/quickblox-google-login)

Comment: @igor-khomenkoThe problem with setting the `external ID` with Parse `User ID` is that I can't. Parse user ID (or more specifically speaking the `objectId`) is an alphanumeric value; On the other hand, QuickBlox only takes an integer value as an `external ID`