# Can I integrate other authentication proviers with Quickblox?

Tags: ios, oauth, quickblox, twitter-digits

I have integrated Quickblox into my app and I would like to use a SMS authentication service ([Digits](https://dev.twitter.com/twitter-kit/ios) from Twitter).

Because, AFAIK, Quickblox does not support server side code to validate the OAuth token, is there a way I could integrate Digits, so the authentication is done safely? (server side validation of token).

Comment: So you would like to add use Digits and QuickBlox in one app or just use SMS authentication with QuickBlox?

Comment: I would like to use Digits and Quickblox in one app to do SMS authentication. Are the any other options, you would recommend for this?

Comment: Possible solution is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24831440/quickblox-google-login

Comment: Thanks, but I don't really like the solution. From Digits, I get an access token, which I would like to validate on the serverside, so I know that authentication is correct.
Is there no way to make a call from Quickblox serverside to Digits Echo service, during a log in?