# Quickblox - authentication integration - does the password ever expire?

Tags: quickblox

As seen on this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/24929123/102957 the recommended method for authentication integration is to create users with a faux password (stored somewhere else or derived from the user data).

I find this authentication integration less robust than what I would like it to be.

When using this method:

1. will the password expire?
2. if the user, using some hacky technique, goes and changes the password, it will break completely, how can I restore the account password *without* knowing the previous password but having the quickblox account secret? Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

1. Password never expires
2. You can reset user's password by email http://quickblox.com/developers/Users#Reset_API_User_password_by_e-mail

Comment: Thank you @Igor, is there a way to do that programmatically? Having the app key+secret, could it be possible to do that? (I can totally wipe out the user account, but I can't change its password?) Thanks!